# How to access DB execution error when using MySQL for Swift

Tags: swift, vapor

Here's the snippet (here mysql is an instance of [MySQL for Swift](https://github.com/vapor/mysql)):

```
do {
    try mysql.execute("INSERT INTO ...")
} catch {
    print(error) // here will print out the actual MySQL error message
    return error.localizedDescription // return "The operation couldn’t be completed. (MySQL.Error error 6.)" The real message from the DB is lost.
}
```

In the 1st line of the catch section, the print statement is able to spit out the real error message from DB, but the 2nd line only returns a generic statement:
`The operation couldn’t be completed. (MySQL.Error error 6.)`

How do I access the underlining error message from the database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically catch the `MySQLError` so you can access its properties.

```
} catch let error as MySQLError {
    print(error.reason)
}
```

https://github.com/vapor/mysql/blob/master/Sources/MySQL/Error.swift#L8